# Shopify template not triggering liquid scripting language

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am new to shopify liquid, I am trying to get a specific collection to be output to page, but i not sure why liquid part is not functioning. The text is displaying and page.content works but nothing work on for loop

page name is "page.test.liquid"

I'm using this for a template for page called monthly products

**{%- assign collection = collections['past-crates'] -%}  <-- always add this if not in collection page, and make sure you set collection properly**

```
{{ page.content }}

{%- assign collection = collections['past-crates'] -%}

{%- for product in collection.products -%}
 {{product.title | capitalize}}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `collection` object is `nil` unless you are on a collection page. If you want to access a specific collection object on another page you can access it via the global [collections object](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#collections):

```
{%- assign collection = collections['your-collection-handle'] -%}
```

Comment: it still does not work even when i did this

Comment: @ONEPOINTONE just to be safe: Can you confirm that there actually are products in the specified collection?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ,I realized my issue was collection was no set properly, I just wish shopify return a null or [] for empty collection.